# nginx rewrite not end with .php extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm using nginx to rewrite a URL like
`http://www.sample.com/application` to `http://www.sample.com/index.php/application`

rewrite rule is

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 break;
}
```

My fastcgi config is

```
location ~ \index.php {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
```

But the rewrite rule is not working.
And I browse `http://www.sample.com/index.php/application` is not working also.
the `/application` not passing to index.php

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

If you `break` from a `rewrite` rule, the location context remains unchanged. You need to use `last` not `break` so that your *fastcgi* location is eventually found.

Also, you have a redundant backslash in your regex rule. It should probably be:

```
location ~ ^/index.php { ... }
```

Comment: sorry.it doesn't work. not passing the /application arg to index.php.

Comment: @Magic I've tested it and it does work. How your `index.php` receives the argument depends on what you have put into `fastcgi_params`. It will receive the `/application` as part of the REQUEST_URI anyway, but if you want to add a PATH_INFO parameter, you may need to add your own `fastcgi_param` See https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/